# can I Run a Stored Procedure across all SQL servers and return 1 html report

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, stored-procedures

I have the following set up as a sp and it runs daily. It gives me a report for each SQL cluster in my environment but what I'd like to do is configure it to run across all clusters and return 1 report with the data from all of the clusters. For example I've got 6 clusters throughout my org and I get 6 reports daily on back up aging. I'd like to be able to get 1 report with the info from each. The following is my sp.

```
USE [IT_MAINTENANCE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BackupAgingReport]    Script Date: 12/20/2013 10:22:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--exec dbo.BackupAgingReport @emailTo = 'email address'

-- =============================================
-- Author:      IT
-- Create date: 2013-12-18
-- Description: Backup Aging Report,  Send e-mail in HTML Format
--
-- Version History
--   2013-12-18: added sys.databases.status_desc = 'ONLINE' filter
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BackupAgingReport]
    @emailTo varchar(250) = 'email address',
    @ageFull int = 168, -- 1Week
    @ageDiff int = 24,  -- 24 Hours
    @ageLog  int = 60   -- 30 Minutes
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

    SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Full Backup Aging Report</H1>' +
    N'<i>Threshold: ' + Convert(varchar(10),@ageFull) + ' Hours</i>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Server</th><th>Database</th><th>Last Backup</th><th>Backup Age Hours</th></tr>' +
    IsNull(CAST ( ( SELECT 
                td = CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) , '', 
                td = msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  '', 
                td = convert(varchar(10),MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date),120) ,  '', 
                td = DATEDIFF(hh, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), GETDATE())  
                FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset inner join sys.databases on msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = sys.databases.name 
                WHERE     msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'D' and
                    sys.databases.state_desc = 'ONLINE'
                GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
                HAVING      (MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(hh, - @ageFull, GETDATE()))  
                ORDER BY  msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ), '') +
    N'</table>' +

    N'<H1>Missing Full Backup Report</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Server</th><th>Database</th><th>Last Backup</th><th>Backup Age Hours</th></tr>' +
    IsNull(CAST ( (  
                SELECT      
                   td = CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')),   '', 
                   td = master.dbo.sysdatabases.NAME,   '', 
                   td = 'Never',   '', 
                   td = 9999   
                FROM 
                   master.dbo.sysdatabases LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
                       ON master.dbo.sysdatabases.name  = msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
                WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name IS NULL AND master.dbo.sysdatabases.name <> 'tempdb' 
                ORDER BY  msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ),'') +              
    N'</table>' +

    N'<H1>Diff Backup Aging Report</H1>' +
    N'<i>Threshold: ' + Convert(varchar(10),@ageDiff) + ' Hours</i>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Server</th><th>Database</th><th>Last Backup</th><th>Backup Age Hours</th></tr>' +
    isnull(CAST ( ( SELECT 
                td = CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) , '', 
                td = msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  '', 
                td = convert(varchar(10),MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date),120) ,  '', 
                td = DATEDIFF(hh, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), GETDATE())  
                FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset inner join sys.databases on msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = sys.databases.name 
                WHERE     msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'I'  and
                    sys.databases.state_desc = 'ONLINE'
                GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
                HAVING      (MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(hh, - @ageDiff, GETDATE()))  
                ORDER BY  msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ), '') +
    N'</table>' +

    N'<H1>Log Backup Aging Report</H1>' +
    N'<i>Threshold: ' + Convert(varchar(10),@ageLog) + ' Minutes</i>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Server</th><th>Database</th><th>Last Backup</th><th>Backup Age Minutes</th></tr>' +
    isnull(CAST ( ( SELECT 
                td = CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) , '', 
                td = msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  '', 
                td = convert(varchar(16),MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date),120) ,  '', 
                td = DATEDIFF(mi, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), GETDATE())  
                FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset inner join sys.databases on msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = sys.databases.name 
                WHERE     msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'L'  and
                    sys.databases.state_desc = 'ONLINE'
                GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
                HAVING      (MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(mi, - @ageLog, GETDATE()))  
                ORDER BY  msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ), '') +
    N'</table>' 

    --print @tableHTML
DECLARE @eSubject varchar(250)
SET @eSubject = 'Backup Aging Report (' + Convert(varchar(250),SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) + ')'    
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=@emailTo,
    @subject = @eSubject,
    @body = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML' ;

END
```

*EDIT****

Now that I have my tbl_FullBackupAging set up and I'm using a SP how do I insert into my tbl if it's coming from a different SQL Server?

Here's basically what my SP looks like.

```
Declare @ageFull int = 168 --1Week
INSERT INTO [SQLSERVER].[IT_MAINTENANCE].[dbo].[tbl_FullBackupAging]
SELECT 
                CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername'))  As Server, 
                msdb.dbo.backupset.type AS 'Type',
                msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name AS 'Database', 
                convert(varchar(10),MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date),120) AS 'Last Backup', 
                DATEDIFF(hh, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), GETDATE()) AS 'Backup Age Hours' 
                FROM msdb.dbo.backupset inner join sys.databases on msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = sys.databases.name 
                WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'D' and
                    sys.databases.state_desc = 'ONLINE'
                GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, msdb.dbo.backupset.type 
                HAVING (MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(hh, - @ageFull, GETDATE()))  
                ORDER BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name

INSERT INTO [SQLSERVER].[IT_MAINTENANCE].[dbo].[tbl_FullBackupAging]
SELECT      
                CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS 'Server', 
                'NEVER' AS 'Type',
                master.dbo.sysdatabases.NAME AS 'Database', 
                'Never' AS 'Last Backup', 
                9999 AS 'Backup Age Hours'  
                FROM 
                   master.dbo.sysdatabases LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
                       ON master.dbo.sysdatabases.name  = msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
                WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name IS NULL AND master.dbo.sysdatabases.name <> 'tempdb' 
                ORDER BY  msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name

DECLARE @ageDiff int = 24 --24Hours 
INSERT INTO [SQLSERVER].[IT_MAINTENANCE].[dbo].[tbl_FullBackupAging]            
SELECT 
                CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS 'Server', 
                msdb.dbo.backupset.type AS 'Type',
                msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name AS 'Database', 
                convert(varchar(10),MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date),120) AS 'Last Backup', 
                DATEDIFF(hh, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), GETDATE()) AS 'Backup Age Hours' 
                FROM msdb.dbo.backupset inner join sys.databases on msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = sys.databases.name 
                WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'I'  and
                    sys.databases.state_desc = 'ONLINE'  and NOT(msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name) IN ('model', 'msdb')
                GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, msdb.dbo.backupset.type
                HAVING (MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(hh, - @ageDiff, GETDATE()))  
                ORDER BY  msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name    


DECLARE @ageLog int = 60 --60Minutes
INSERT INTO [SQLServer].[IT_MAINTENANCE].[dbo].[tbl_FullBackupAging]    
SELECT 
                CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS 'Server', 
                msdb.dbo.backupset.type AS 'Type',
                msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name AS 'Database', 
                convert(varchar(16),MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date),120) AS 'Last Backup', 
                DATEDIFF(mi, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), GETDATE()) AS 'Backup Age Hours' 
                FROM msdb.dbo.backupset inner join sys.databases on msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name = sys.databases.name 
                WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'L'  and
                    sys.databases.state_desc = 'ONLINE'  and NOT(msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name) IN ('model', 'msdb')
                GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, msdb.dbo.backupset.type 
                HAVING (MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(mi, - @ageLog, GETDATE()))  
                ORDER BY  msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is

On all the clusters create a table with same schema as your output. e.g. `tbl_BackupAgingReport`

`Server | Database | Last Backup    | Backup Age Hours`

Then insert into that table by executing the SP.

```
-- truncate table before the next run and then insert
insert into tbl_BackupAgingReport
exec [dbo].[BackupAgingReport]
```

Now you can insert that data into a central server where you can insert using `opendatasource`

```
--Insert back into reporting server and then you can use all the fancy HTML tags to do reporting.

    declare @query nvarchar(max)
    select @query = 'insert opendatasource (''' + 'SQLOLEDB''' + ',''Data Source=ip,port; User ID=sa;Password=strong_password'''+ ').IT_MAINTENANCE.dbo.BackupAgingReport_Final(Server, Database, Last Backup,Backup Age Hours)'+char(10)+
    'select * from tbl_BackupAgingReport'
 print @query
 --exec (@query)
```

Alternatively, use powershell.

Comment: That seems a bit intense. maybe I'm a little too new to this. is there a way that I can just alter the script to run against my 6 different servers to return 1 report?

Comment: @BSanders thats the way that I can think of using T-SQL. You can use Powershell if you want. You just need a way to dump all the results into a central database table, and then you can generate reports out of that.

Comment: Thank you Kin! I set up the tbl and it works perfectly except for if it's coming from a different SQL Server. Can you help me to better understand how I'd work that?

Comment: On the other servers, you have to put in the `opendatasource` pointing to the central server where you will be running the report from. Also, the `ip,port` should be the central server `ip,port`. That way the SQL gets executed on the source servers, but the results get dumped into the central server - the one you will be generating reports from.

Comment: I think I have this all set up. I just have to get a SQL user set up for the opendatasource string.